# Python string split with delimiter

Tags: python

Suppose i have this list `a = ["test", "news", "hello"]` and i need to duplicate each value in list and separate it by delimiter like this.

```
a = [("test","test"),("news","news"),("hello","hello")]
```

I have tried this and got only up to this.

```
a = ["test", "news", "hello"]

b = [l + (''.join(l,)) for l in a]

print(b)

#['testtest', 'newsnews', 'hellohello']
```

Comment: Do you actually what a tuple of two items per element, or a single string separated by `,` for each element...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it as:

```
a = ["test", "news", "hello"]

>>> print [(i,)*2 for i in a]   #thanks to @JonClements for the suggestion
[('test', 'test'), ('news', 'news'), ('hello', 'hello')]
```

Comment: I'd go for `(i,)*2` for flexibility (for increasing the amounts if ever needed)

Comment: You're welcome... the other option the OP could be after is `[','.join((i,) * 2) for i in a]`

Answer (score 2):

I think the most "pythonic" (and shortest) way to do this is with everyone's favorite confusing built-in, [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip):

```
a = ["test", "news", "hello"]
print zip(a,a) 
>>> [('test', 'test'), ('news', 'news'), ('hello', 'hello')]
```

And, for completeness, I'll point out that in python 3, `zip` returns an iterable.  So to get it to print nicely, you'll want to listify it: `list(zip(a,a))`.  If, however, you want to iterate through it, doing things with the data, you'll want to keep the iterable.  (Potentially massive memory savings for long lists).